# Group Information for an Id within the same document or Split this to two collections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using the Firestore DB with a Flutter application.

In the application, I schedule employees to shifts for the following days.

As a feature, I want to implement a calendar that visualizes employee availability. When an employee is not assigned to a shift or not away he is available.

At the moment I have a collection of **Shifts** and **Employees** within Firebase. I was thinking of creating an **Unavailability** collection but on a second thought that might be unnecessary.

The question is, should I create an **Unavailability** collection within Firebase? Each document would have a property of date, employee name, and reason (employee already assigned, sick, vacation, etc.) Or implement this within the **Employees** collection which already exists. Within this collection, I have stored employee's attributes such as name, salary, email...

My concern with this is that for a given employee document, I will have an attribute with a very long list that contains the unavailability dates. Also, I would like to present the reason for the unavailability. This means I will have to present a shift with its details if the employee is already assigned to a shift or the general unavailability details.

Should I instead implement this within Flutter (3 collections for 1st case)?

Note: If it matters, I am using Bloc for the state management within Flutter.

Comment: If it satisfies the need of a particular query, then yes.  If it doesn't add anything in terms of satisfying requirements, then no.  If you can get by without an extra collection, then leave it of.  Adding a collection on some "best practice" principle alone isn't cost-effective.  You should have an actual need for it.

Comment: @DougStevenson What would be optimal considering the use of Bloc state management for my case? Does the Bloc even impact the choice of the Firestore DB structure? (if not obvious, I am new to this)

Comment: Seems like you're asking for an opinion, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to a general discussion forum instead, such as Reddit, in order to generate some ideas.